# How to prove the Weyl identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

In [the post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26898/normal-ordering-with-vertex-operators-in-conformal-field-theory), there is a formula called *Weyl identity*: 
\begin{align}
\exp\left(-\,{k \over n}\,a_{n}\,z^{-n}\right)
\exp\left({\ell \over n}\,a_{-n}\,w^{n}\right) =
\exp\left({\ell \over n}\,a_{-n}\,w^{n}\right)
\exp\left(-\,{k \over n}\,a_{-n}\,z^{-n}\right)
\exp\left({k\ell \over n}\left[w \over z\right]^{n}\right)
\end{align}
Here $\left[a_n, a_m\right] = n\,\delta_{n\ +\ m,\,0\,\,}$.

I tried to verify this identity by expanding both sides of the identity. But I am not able to verify the identity. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look likes your version of Weyl's identity has a typo in the sign of one of its exponents.

If $[A,B] = c$ where $c$ is a scalar, then
$$\frac{d}{dt} e^{tA} B e^{-tA} = e^{tA} [A,B] e^{-tA} = e^{tA} c e^{-tA} = c$$
This leads to $e^{tA} B e^{-tA} = B + ct$. In particular, $e^A B e^{-A} = B + c$.
As a result,
$$e^A e^B e^{-A} = e^{e^A B e^{-A}} = e^{B + c} = e^B e^c
\quad\implies\quad e^A e^B = e^B e^A e^c.
$$
Substitute $A$ by 
$-\frac{k}{n}a_n z^{-n}$, $B$ by $\frac{\ell}{n} a_{-n} w^n$
and notice

$$[ A, B ] = \left[ -\frac{k}{n}a_n z^{-n}, \frac{\ell}{n} a_{-n} w^n\right]
= -\frac{k}{n}\frac{\ell}{n} \left(\frac{w}{z}\right)^n [ a_n, a_{-n} ] 
= -\frac{k\ell}{n}\left(\frac{w}{z}\right)^n
$$
is a scalar, we find
$$e^{-\frac{k}{n}a_n z^{-n}}
e^{\frac{\ell}{n} a_{-n} w^n}
= e^{\frac{\ell}{n} a_{-n} w^n}
e^{-\frac{k}{n}a_n z^{-n}}
e^{\color{red}{-}\frac{k\ell}{n}\left(\frac{w}{z}\right)^n}$$

Up to a sign in the exponents of last factor, this is the identity you have.

Comment: thank you very much. Why $e^A e^B e^{-A} = e^{e^A B e^{-A}}$?

Comment: This is because $e^{-A} = (e^A)^{-1}$ and for any function $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n x^n$ interpreted as a formal power series. $$Uf(B)U^{-1} = U\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n B^n\right)U^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n UB^nU^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n (UBU^{-1})^n = f(UBU^{-1})$$